# Can we change language of edittext default "Paste" popup?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change language of edittext default "Paste" popup.My phone language is English and i set my app language to Persian. But when i long pressed on edittext the default "Paste" popup shows in Arabic language. I want to change it in English.

[image: Here is screenshot of that]

Comment: you probably want to add your own LongClickListener, which will show your own *paste* popup

Comment: I don't want to make custom popup. is there any other way? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: That's the way I know. Don't know about other ways. Probably there are no other ways, as that popup is created by OS from the OS language. If you want a custom something there - you likely will have to create something custom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to modify context menu of edit text...

You can add, edit and remove any item from menu 
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864704/2692102)

Comment: I don't want to edit,remove and add anything. i just want to change language.

Comment: ContextMenu is way bigger then default popup.

Comment: I tried what you said but it just create new context menu. Actually i don't want to create new one.@Hanzala