# android long press on edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, contextmenu

I have a text edit and I want to be able to select text from it but without (copy, cut and paste)

I can't use editable = "false" because on some devices it will not select

Please if any one can help

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: just return true in your OnLongClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. After a long search in Internet I found a good information which help me.

This is where you can find detailed information how to make a custom Contextual Actions not just for text: [link](http://hmkcode.com/android-contextual-action-mode/)

This is where you can find a solution for your issue -> [Old StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles)

It was very helpful for me, hope it will be helpful for you, too.