# How to add a share button to the text selection bar for an EditText?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I notice that when highlighting text in a WebView a share button appears along with the standard copy and select all buttons:

[image: WebView text selected]

but when highlighting text in a TextView or EditText, there is no such button.

[image: EditText text selected]

Is there any way to add such a button via XML or can it be done programmatically?

Comment: Could you please provide an image shows the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that by setting a custom selection action mode using

`TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(ActionMode.Callback)`

and so the `EditText`

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles) a similar question with that was answered with an example

Also visit [TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29)