# Is it possible to add a button to Text selection option in android?

Tags: android, textselection

I want to add a button to text selection options (in all app see that button)?

[image]

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572711/how-to-add-a-share-button-to-the-text-selection-bar-for-an-edittext)

Comment: Globally means? Through out your app or other apps too?

Comment: every edittext text selection option should see that button?