# Get Selected Text from TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to get the text the user selected in a TextView,
i wan't to use the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` to allow my user copy/paste actions

However I don't have a clue as how to get the text once the action bar menu is displayed, the goal is to implement a Google book like behavior : you select a word and it gives you a definition.

Comment: This attribute is merely to allow the text inside the TextView to be copied or not.

Comment: I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13004720/460053 to be better than the one below for my particular use case.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`. This will allow you to create your own `ActionMode.Callback` for when the text is selected. Then you can use `TextView.getSelectionStart` and `TextView.getSelectionEnd` to retrieve the selected text when your `MenuItem` is selected. Here's a quick example:

```
    mTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Remove the "select all" option
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
            // Remove the "cut" option
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
            // Remove the "copy all" option
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.copy);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Called when action mode is first created. The menu supplied
            // will be used to generate action buttons for the action mode

            // Here is an example MenuItem
            menu.add(0, DEFINITION, 0, "Definition").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_book);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Called when an action mode is about to be exited and
            // destroyed
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case DEFINITION:
                    int min = 0;
                    int max = mTextView.getText().length();
                    if (mTextView.isFocused()) {
                        final int selStart = mTextView.getSelectionStart();
                        final int selEnd = mTextView.getSelectionEnd();

                        min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
                        max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));
                    }
                    // Perform your definition lookup with the selected text
                    final CharSequence selectedText = mTextView.getText().subSequence(min, max);
                    // Finish and close the ActionMode
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for, I found the getSelectionStart and so on but was looking for the custom action mode !

Comment: this is a nice solution

Comment: is there a way I can highlight the selected text.

Comment: What about calling `menu.clear()` in `onPrepareActionMode()`? It might be faster and safer.

Comment: dont forget `mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);`