# How to add more options to Android default Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

As we know, by default, after selecting some text on views, android displays Contextual Action Bar (CAB) with some default options, such as: copy, cut, select all...

*Now, I want to have an application (that has only 2 options: ON/OFF), If I turn it ON, Some other options will be added to default CAB. If I turn it OFF, my custom options will be removed from Android default CAB.*

**My question is: Is it possible to Add/Remove some options to this default CAB? How can I make above application?**

Thank you!

Comment: [TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833303/420015) is what you're looking for.

Comment: How can I apply this change to all TextView for all applications? As i mentioned, I want to make an application with only 2 options ON and OFF: If I select ON, some options will be add to CAB, If I select OFF, they will be moved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` on each of your TextViews.

You can have a boolean:

```
boolean on = true;
```

Then create a method that actually edits the CAB like so:

```
private void editContextualActionBar(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
    if (on) {
        // adds a new menu item to the CAB
        // add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes)
        menu.add(0, R.id.action_to_be_performed, 1, R.string.action_name);
    } else {
        // removes the new menu item
        menu.removeItem(R.id.action_to_be_performed);
    }
}
```

Finally, call the Callback on your TextView with the editContextualActionBar method in onCreateActionMode and perform the menu action in onActionItemClicked:

```
textView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            editContextualActionBar(mode, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_to_be_performed:
                    // perform action
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    });
```