# Extracting words from TextView after click/press on them

Tags: android, textview, text-extraction

is there any easy way to select whole words from TextView by touching them? This functionality is in dictionary app ColorDict.

1. Search for word "word"
2. [Select word "theorem"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hES89.png) and it now appears in the  search box so I can search it faster by clicking on search.

I want to be able to select those words. That ScrollView which is on top is misleading. It appears after selecting ["Select a word"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGN5v.png) in dialog which appears after long press on something in TextView (you can see word "theorem" on the bottom - long press on "theorem").

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this attribute to your `TextView`:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

**EDIT:**

```
private static final int MENU_ITEM_ID = 0x42;
private TextView targetTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    targetTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.target_textview);
    targetTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // you can remove the default menu items if you wish
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.copy);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            /*
            * called when the action mode is created. Here you can
            * generate action buttons for this action mode.
            * */
            menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_ID, 0, "Menu Item").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // called when the action mode is about to be destroyed
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case MENU_ITEM_ID:
                    int start = targetTextView.getSelectionStart();
                    int end = targetTextView.getSelectionEnd();
                    CharSequence selectedText = targetTextView.getText().subSequence(start, end);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selectedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, and how to make it select whole word after short press? How to trigger something after short press on the word? There is some handler?

Comment: I've added sample code to enable this functionality. However, beware that this is available as of API level 11. I am unsure how to do this for earlier Android versions.

Comment: Did this resolve your problem? If yes, please mark this answer as accepted. If not, please provide more information on the issues.

Comment: Thank you for example and guiding me to setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback method. Didn't find this. After I googled this method I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832123/get-selected-text-from-textview on SO and it seems very similar. I don't want to select words by this way, but right now rethought priorities. I will get back to this after some other problem I am facing right now. I want to extract text by simply Touch (with that touch automaticaly select whole word) -> (automaticaly) Put word to EditText. But thanks.. accepting on the way.