# Android TextView copy text bar

Tags: android, text, click, copy

I would like to have the possibility to mark and copy text in a TextView.

I want to overwrite onLongClick method. 
It should be working like in android browser. Just click, mark text and press copy. Is there a solution who works in most of android versions?
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832123/get-selected-text-from-textview , maybe this is what you seek?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your TextView:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Note: Available from API level 11

Comment: When I set android:textIsSelectable="true" I can select text yes. But It is not possible to copy the selected text. There is a button who copies the whole text and not only the selected one

Comment: This really depends on the device you are testing on...For example I tested this feature on a pure Android device (Nexus 5) and you can copy the selected text or the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
textView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() { 

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {

            Log.d(TAG, "long clicked");

            return true; 
        } 
    });
```