# How to display popup instead of CAB when textview is selected?

Tags: android, textview, android-popupwindow, android-actionmode

I am making a reading app and it has a full screen activity.
When user selects the part of the text a `contextual action bar` appears with option of copy. This is the default behaviour. But this actionbar blocks the text under it so user cannot select it.

I want to show a popup window like below.
[image]

I tried returning `false` from `onCreateActionMode` but when i do this i can't select the text either.

I want to know if there is a standart way to achieve this as many reading applications use this design.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know how Play Books achieves this, but you could create a [`PopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and calculate where to position it based on the selected text using [`Layout.getSelectionPath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getSelectionPath(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Path)) and a little bit of math. Basically, we're going to:

- Calculate the bounds of the selected text
- Calculate the bounds and initial location of the `PopupWindow`
- Calculate the difference between the two
- Offset the `PopupWindow` to rest center horizontally/vertically above or below the selected text

**Calculating the selection bounds**

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html#getSelectionPath(int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Path)):

> Fills in the specified Path with a representation of a highlight
>   between the specified offsets. This will often be a rectangle or a
>   potentially discontinuous set of rectangles. If the start and end are
>   the same, the returned path is empty.

So, the specified offsets in our case would be the start and end of the selection, which can be found using [`Selection.getSelectionStart`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#getSelectionStart(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [`Selection.getSelectionEnd`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#getSelectionEnd(java.lang.CharSequence)). For convenience, `TextView` gives us [`TextView.getSelectionStart`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart()), [`TextView.getSelectionEnd`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionEnd()) and [`TextView.getLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLayout()).

```
    final Path selDest = new Path();
    final RectF selBounds = new RectF();
    final Rect outBounds = new Rect();

    // Calculate the selection start and end offset
    final int selStart = yourTextView.getSelectionStart();
    final int selEnd = yourTextView.getSelectionEnd();
    final int min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
    final int max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));

    // Calculate the selection outBounds
    yourTextView.getLayout().getSelectionPath(min, max, selDest);
    selDest.computeBounds(selBounds, true /* this param is ignored */);
    selBounds.roundOut(outBounds);
```

Now that we have a [`Rect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) of the selected text bounds, we can choose where we want to place the `PopupWindow` relative to it. In this case, we'll center it horizontally along the top or bottom of the selected text, depending on how much space we have to display our popup.

**Calculating the initial popup coordinates**

Next we'll need to calculate the bounds of the popup content. To do this, we'll first need to call [`PopupWindow.showAtLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int)), but the bounds of the `View` we inflate won't immediately be available, so I'd recommend using a [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) to wait for them to become available.

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(yourTextView, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
```

`PopupWindow.showAtLocation` requires:

- A `View` to retrieve a valid [`Window` token](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowToken()) from, which just uniquely identifies the `Window` to place the popup in
- An optional gravity, but in our case it'll be `Gravity.TOP`
- Optional x/y offsets

Since we can't determine the x/y offset until the popup content is laid out, we'll just initially place it at the default location. If you try to call `PopupWindow.showAtLocation` before the `View` you pass in has been laid out, you'll receive a [`WindowManager.BadTokenException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.BadTokenException.html), so you may consider using a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to avoid that, but it mostly comes up when you have text selected and rotate your device.

```
    final Rect cframe = new Rect();
    final int[] cloc = new int[2];
    popupContent.getLocationOnScreen(cloc);
    popupContent.getLocalVisibleRect(cbounds);
    popupContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(cframe);

    final int scrollY = ((View) yourTextView.getParent()).getScrollY();
    final int[] tloc = new int[2];
    yourTextView.getLocationInWindow(tloc);

    final int startX = cloc[0] + cbounds.centerX();
    final int startY = cloc[1] + cbounds.centerY() - (tloc[1] - cframe.top) - scrollY;
```

- [`View.getLocationOnScreen`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])) will return us the x/y coordinates for the popup content.
- [`View.getLocalVisibleRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocalVisibleRect(android.graphics.Rect)) will return  us the bounds of the popup content
- [`View.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(android.graphics.Rect)) will return us the offsets to accommodate for the action bar, if present
- [`View.getScrollY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY()) will return us the `y` offset for whatever scroll container our `TextView` is in (`ScrollView` in my case)
- [`View.getLocationInWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])) will return us the `y` offset for our `TextView`, in case the action bar pushes it down a little

Once we've gotten all of the info we need, we can calculate the final starting x/y of the popup content and then use this to figure out the difference between them and the selected text `Rect` so we can [`PopupWindow.update`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#update(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to the new location.

**Calculating the offset popup coordinates**

```
    // Calculate the top and bottom offset of the popup relative to the selection bounds
    final int popupHeight = cbounds.height();
    final int textPadding = yourTextView.getPaddingLeft();
    final int topOffset = Math.round(selBounds.top - startY);
    final int btmOffset = Math.round(selBounds.bottom - (startY - popupHeight));

    // Calculate the x/y coordinates for the popup relative to the selection bounds
    final int x = Math.round(selBounds.centerX() + textPadding - startX);
    final int y = Math.round(selBounds.top - scrollY < startY ? btmOffset : topOffset);
```

If there's enough room to display the popup above the selected text, we'll put it there; otherwise, we'll offset it below the selected text. In my case, I have `16dp` padding around my `TextView`, so that needs to be taken into account too. We'll end up with the final `x` and `y` location to offset the `PopupWindow` with.

```
    popupWindow.update(x, y, -1, -1);
```

`-1` here just represents the default width/height for we supplied for the `PopupWindow`, in our case it'll be [`ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT)

**Listening for selection changes**

We want the `PopupWindow` to update every time we change the selected text.

An easy way to listen for selection changes is to subclass `TextView` and provide a callback to [`TextView.onSelectionChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onSelectionChanged(int,%20int)).

```
public class NotifyingSelectionTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private SelectionChangeListener listener;

    public NotifyingSelectionTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
        if (listener != null) {
            if (hasSelection()) {
                listener.onTextSelected();
            } else {
                listener.onTextUnselected();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSelectionChangeListener(SelectionChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface SelectionChangeListener {
        void onTextSelected();
        void onTextUnselected();
    }

}
```

**Listening for scroll changes**

If you have a `TextView` in a scroll container like `ScrollView`, you may also want to listen for scroll changes so that you can anchor your popup while you're scrolling. An easy way to listen for those is to subclass `ScrollView` and provide a callback to [`View.onScrollChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

```
public class NotifyingScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private ScrollChangeListener listener;

    public NotifyingScrollView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onScrollChanged();
        }
    }

    public void setScrollChangeListener(ScrollChangeListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface ScrollChangeListener {
        void onScrollChanged();
    }

}
```

**Creating an empty [`ActionMode.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html)**

Like you mention in your post, we'll need to return `true` in [`ActionMode.Callback.onCreateActionMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html#onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode,%20android.view.Menu)) in order for our text to remain selectable. But we'll also need to call [`Menu.clear`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#clear()) in [`ActionMode.Callback.onPrepareActionMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html#onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode,%20android.view.Menu)) in order to remove all the items you may find in an `ActionMode` for selected text.

```
/** An {@link ActionMode.Callback} used to remove all action items from text selection */
static final class EmptyActionMode extends SimpleActionModeCallback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Return true to ensure the text is still selectable
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Remove all action items to provide an actionmode-less selection
        menu.clear();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now we can use [`TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(android.view.ActionMode.Callback)) to apply our custom `ActionMode`. `SimpleActionModeCallback` is a custom class that just provides stubs for `ActionMode.Callback`, kinda similar to [`ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)

```
public class SimpleActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }

}
```

**Layouts**

This is the `Activity` layout we're using:

```
<your.package.name.NotifyingScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notifying_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <your.package.name.NotifyingSelectionTextView
        android:id="@+id/notifying_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</your.package.name.NotifyingScrollView>
```

This is our popup layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/action_mode_popup_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_add_note"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_note_add_black_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_translate"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_translate_black_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_search"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_red"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupSwatch"
            android:src="@drawable/round_red" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_yellow"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupSwatch"
            android:src="@drawable/round_yellow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_green"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupSwatch"
            android:src="@drawable/round_green" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_blue"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupSwatch"
            android:src="@drawable/round_blue" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/view_action_mode_popup_clear_format"
            style="@style/ActionModePopupSwatch"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_format_clear_black_24dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

These are our popup button styles:

```
<style name="ActionModePopupButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:background">?selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionModePopupSwatch" parent="ActionModePopupButton">
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
</style>
```

**Util**

The `ViewUtils.onGlobalLayout` you'll see is just a util method for handling some `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` boilerplate.

```
public static void onGlobalLayout(final View view, final Runnable runnable) {
    final OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            runnable.run();
        }

    };
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```

**Bringing it altogether**

So, now that we've:

- Calculated the selected text bounds
- Calculated the popup bounds
- Calculated the difference and determined the popup offsets
- Provided a way to listen for scroll changes and selection changes
- Created our `Activity` and popup layouts

Bringing everything together may look something like:

```
public class ActionModePopupActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ScrollChangeListener, SelectionChangeListener {

    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = -1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = -1;

    private final Point currLoc = new Point();
    private final Point startLoc = new Point();

    private final Rect cbounds = new Rect();
    private final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow();
    private final ActionMode.Callback emptyActionMode = new EmptyActionMode();

    private NotifyingSelectionTextView yourTextView;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_mode_popup);

        // Initialize the popup content, only add it to the Window once we've selected text
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        popupWindow.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_action_mode_popup, null));
        popupWindow.setWidth(WRAP_CONTENT);
        popupWindow.setHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);

        // Initialize to the NotifyingScrollView to observe scroll changes
        final NotifyingScrollView scroll
                = (NotifyingScrollView) findViewById(R.id.notifying_scroll_view);
        scroll.setScrollChangeListener(this);

        // Initialize the TextView to observe selection changes and provide an empty ActionMode
        yourTextView = (NotifyingSelectionTextView) findViewById(R.id.notifying_text_view);
        yourTextView.setText(IPSUM);
        yourTextView.setSelectionChangeListener(this);
        yourTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(emptyActionMode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        // Anchor the popup while the user scrolls
        if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
            final Point ploc = calculatePopupLocation();
            popupWindow.update(ploc.x, ploc.y, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextSelected() {
        final View popupContent = popupWindow.getContentView();
        if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
            // Calculate the updated x/y pop coordinates
            final Point ploc = calculatePopupLocation();
            popupWindow.update(ploc.x, ploc.y, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        } else {
        // Add the popup to the Window and position it relative to the selected text bounds
        ViewUtils.onGlobalLayout(yourTextView, () -> {
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(yourTextView, TOP, 0, 0);
            // Wait for the popup content to be laid out
            ViewUtils.onGlobalLayout(popupContent, () -> {
                final Rect cframe = new Rect();
                final int[] cloc = new int[2];
                popupContent.getLocationOnScreen(cloc);
                popupContent.getLocalVisibleRect(cbounds);
                popupContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(cframe);

                final int scrollY = ((View) yourTextView.getParent()).getScrollY();
                final int[] tloc = new int[2];
                yourTextView.getLocationInWindow(tloc);

                final int startX = cloc[0] + cbounds.centerX();
                final int startY = cloc[1] + cbounds.centerY() - (tloc[1] - cframe.top) - scrollY;
                startLoc.set(startX, startY);

                final Point ploc = calculatePopupLocation();
                popupWindow.update(ploc.x, ploc.y, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
            });
        });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextUnselected() {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
    }

    /** Used to calculate where we should position the {@link PopupWindow} */
    private Point calculatePopupLocation() {
        final ScrollView parent = (ScrollView) yourTextView.getParent();

        // Calculate the selection start and end offset
        final int selStart = yourTextView.getSelectionStart();
        final int selEnd = yourTextView.getSelectionEnd();
        final int min = Math.max(0, Math.min(selStart, selEnd));
        final int max = Math.max(0, Math.max(selStart, selEnd));

        // Calculate the selection bounds
        final RectF selBounds = new RectF();
        final Path selection = new Path();
        yourTextView.getLayout().getSelectionPath(min, max, selection);
        selection.computeBounds(selBounds, true /* this param is ignored */);

        // Retrieve the center x/y of the popup content
        final int cx = startLoc.x;
        final int cy = startLoc.y;

        // Calculate the top and bottom offset of the popup relative to the selection bounds
        final int popupHeight = cbounds.height();
        final int textPadding = yourTextView.getPaddingLeft();
        final int topOffset = Math.round(selBounds.top - cy);
        final int btmOffset = Math.round(selBounds.bottom - (cy - popupHeight));

        // Calculate the x/y coordinates for the popup relative to the selection bounds
        final int scrollY = parent.getScrollY();
        final int x = Math.round(selBounds.centerX() + textPadding - cx);
        final int y = Math.round(selBounds.top - scrollY < cy ? btmOffset : topOffset);
        currLoc.set(x, y - scrollY);
        return currLoc;
    }

    /** An {@link ActionMode.Callback} used to remove all action items from text selection */
    static final class EmptyActionMode extends SimpleActionModeCallback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Return true to ensure the yourTextView is still selectable
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Remove all action items to provide an actionmode-less selection
            menu.clear();
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

**Results**

[With the action bar (link to video)](https://gfycat.com/IdioticParchedIvorybilledwoodpecker):

[image: with action bar - no animation]

[Without the action bar (link to video)](https://gfycat.com/ImpartialShyAmericankestrel):

[image: without action bar - no animation]

**Bonus - animation**

Because we know the starting location of the `PopupWindow` and the offset location as the selection changes, we can easily perform a linear interpolation between the two values to create a nice animation when we're moving things around.

```
public static float lerp(float a, float b, float v) {
    return a + (b - a) * v;
}
```

---

```
private static final int DEFAULT_ANIM_DUR = 350;
private static final int DEFAULT_ANIM_DELAY = 500;

@Override
public void onTextSelected() {
    final View popupContent = popupWindow.getContentView();
    if (popupWindow.isShowing()) {
        // Calculate the updated x/y pop coordinates
        popupContent.getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        popupContent.postDelayed(() -> {
            // The current x/y location of the popup
            final int currx = currLoc.x;
            final int curry = currLoc.y;
            // Calculate the updated x/y pop coordinates
            final Point ploc = calculatePopupLocation();
            currLoc.set(ploc.x, ploc.y);
            // Linear interpolate between the current and updated popup coordinates
            final ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
            anim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                final float v = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                final int x = Math.round(AnimUtils.lerp(currx, ploc.x, v));
                final int y = Math.round(AnimUtils.lerp(curry, ploc.y, v));
                popupWindow.update(x, y, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
            });
            anim.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIM_DUR);
            anim.start();
        }, DEFAULT_ANIM_DELAY);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Results**

[With the action bar - animation (link to video)](https://gfycat.com/MaleDirectBluefintuna)

[image: with action bar - animation]

**Extra**

I don't go into how to attach on click listeners to the popup actions and there are probably several ways to achieve this same effect with different calculations and implementations. But I will mention that if you wanted to retrieve the selected text and then do something with it, [you'd just need to `CharSequence.subSequence` the `min` and `max` from the selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833303/420015).

Anyway, I hope this has been helpful! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for such information, I will give it a try when i first have the time