# Can I select the some specific text from long string and perform action on selected text

Tags: android-studio

You can check this screen short  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwdQq.png) Basically I want to applying different formats on my text, I just want to select a some text area from long string and apply like bold, underline or some other actions perform on selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to highlight text.

```
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("A test message");
    spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), {start_index), {end_index}, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannable);
```

Here is a post that shows you how to make your text selectable and how to get the start and end index.

[Get Selected Text from TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832123/get-selected-text-from-textview)

This is the reference to using spannable and you can use it to figure out the rest of your text changes to the string. There are many options available.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan