# how to enable select/copy texts in android?

Tags: android, select, button, text, copy

this is my app strategy:

- there is a text view that contains texts.
- for editing them, i define Action mode items(e.g. EDIT- this will
  texts of text view into edit text)although there are some default
  actions like select all/copy/.. as selecting text, so i don not want
  to define them.

i use this code for enabling  the default selecting/copy buttons.
but as i clicked the buttons, nothing happens. why???
xml code:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/speech"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:textSize="25sp" android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:background="@drawable/curved_background"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"  />
```

initializing TextView in class:

```
 speech_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speech);
 registerForContextMenu(speech_text);
    speech_text.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    speech_text.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new SelectText());
```

SelectingText java class:

```
public class SelectText implements ActionMode.Callback {

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {


    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.text_select, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    //  Log.d(Log, String.format("onActionItemClicked item=%s/%d", item.toString(), item.getItemId()));

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case ... //other actions
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

}
}
```

Note:
as i control my code. the problem is in defining `SelectText` class in this line: `speech_text.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new SelectText());` because as i delete thiscode, every thing worksgood!

Comment: Late to the party, but... I think your problem is that you are always returning `true` from `onActionItemClicked()` - you should return `false` if the item clicked is not one your code handles so that the default actions will be performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your text in app enable for copy/paste in clipboard by adding below line :

```
android:textIsSelectable
```

For more information, Please check below reference,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Thanks.

Comment: i do it. but nothing happen.what should i do?

Comment: @MinaDahesh : I have tried this in my demo and its working.. Just keep above mentioned line and remove code related to it from activity :)

Comment: my app strategy is as an edit button click,all texts of TextView are gone to Edit text. in this case,the select/copy/paste are running correctly. but  it doesn't so in text view.

Comment: @MinaDahesh : Try to debug :)

Comment: @AndGeeky. as i click to have COPY process, this logs are happen:`05-05 20:52:47.571 10521-10521/PACKAGEI/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@37c72d83 time:24007728
05-05 20:52:51.051 10521-10521/PACKAGE D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
` what is your opinion?

Comment: @MinaDahesh : Can you edit your question with detailed explanation? like what you want to do in steps ?

Comment: thanks for your help! i update my question. i think the problem is in `speech_text.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new SelectText());`- as i comment it, actions work.

Comment: why you did not answer me?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.
In your xml jus make sure that....

```
android:focusable="true"

android:textIsSelectable="true"
```