# How to remove default context menu in Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]I am using `EditText` in my Android application. When i long press on the `EditText`, i want to remove/hide all the default context menu like Copy,Cut,Select All etc. Only paste menu should be shown. I have tried with the solution in the below link, but along with Paste, SelectAll option is also showing. How can i remove it.

[EditText: Disable Paste/Replace menu pop-up on Text Selection Handler click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869983/edittext-disable-paste-replace-menu-pop-up-on-text-selection-handler-click-even/28893714#28893714)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: There is a requirement in my project, where if a user copies a text from his phone and the returns to our app, on long pressing in edit text he should be only provided with option to Paste

Comment: @Prem Partially it is. But here i want to show Paste option instead of totally disabling all the default menus

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);
yourEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) 
    { 
        // Do your stuff here when you destroy
    }
    });
}
```

In your xml file, add following line to your respective editText:

```
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

For further operations you can use that library:

https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI

Comment: @MSaasLakhan "Do your stuff here when you destroy" how can i only enable Paste option here and hide rest including select all.

Comment: please check updated answer. Let me know if it works for you buddy and dont forget to mark this post as answer if this works for you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @MSaadLakhan Thank you for for your code,but sorry to say, it didnt helped much.

Comment: I have updated my Question with a photo. As you can see select all is still showing up.I want only paste to be there

Comment: bro look updated answer

Comment: Even that library didnt meet my requirement. Tried it.

Comment: Buddy then you are in real mess. Best of luck keep digging :)

Comment: It seems so. Basically i need to figure it out how to remove the Select All menu option.

Comment: Like there is a method named canPaste, is there any similar method for Select?

Comment: All the solutions work when we select a text in EditText and long press. But when we long press next to the text, none of the solutions work