# Select text and show customized menu instead of default context menu

Tags: android, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to make a book application in React Native. I want that make text selectable but don't want to show default context menu (copy, select all etc). Instead, I want to show a horizontal menu with icons like that:

[image: React Native Context Menu]

Is it possible in react native (maybe with free or paid extension) ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried React Native Selectable Text? found [here](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text).

repo: https://github.com/Astrocoders/react-native-selectable-text

Comment: Please, share the repository link of the project too.

Comment: It is useful for customized menu but it support only text. But I want to add icons etc. to context menu

Comment: maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995439/custom-cut-copy-action-bar-for-edittext-that-shows-text-selection-handles/13004720#13004720